# How to cache Facebook User Info with Facebook Login in IOS App

Tags: facebook, ios5, facebook-login

I am integrating Facebook SDK 3.1 to my iOS 5 app. After Facebook Login, I have to query like this to get user info

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT uid, name, pic_big,username FROM user where uid = me()";

NSDictionary *queryParam =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) { ....
```

Now there are two issues with this approach:

1- User has just waited to get himself authenticated from Facebook and
   now just after that he has to wait again for to get his basic profile info 
   to be fetched from web.

-Q- How can I fetch this info with the Facebook Login web call?

-2- When user reopens the app from login screen, if FBSession is still open and valid Facebok will re-authenticate that user but I would still have to get his basic
profile info from web...

-Q- How can I cache user's basic profile info in my app? Is there any id in FBSession object on which I could cache the user info?

Thanks in advance.
Moeen.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- User has just waited to get himself authenticated from Facebook and
>   now just after that he has to wait again for to get his basic profile
>   info to be fetched from web.
>
> -Q- How can I fetch this info with the Facebook Login web call ?

The original wait times should be minimal with proper usage. You cannot "append" an API call to a login request. Facebook used to have a preload_fql tool, but no longer supports that.

> -2- When user reopens the app from login screen, if FBSession is still open and valid Facebok will re-authenticate that user but I would
>   still have to get his basic profile info from web ...
>
> -Q- How can I cache user's basic profile info in my app ? Is there any id in FBSession object on which I could cache the user info ?

This is a matter of your application design. My suggestion would to create a NSMutableDictionary as a class property, and call it `cached_user_data` or something. Save user data in there.

Comment: Hi @Tommy Crush thanks for your feedback. Regarding Q2, I can save the user's data in some dictionary but for that I need some ID. And my problem is I could't find any id in FBSession object to relate it to current user. My app can be used by different Facebook users, so I would need some ID from FBSession , so once user is logged in I could get his info from cache dictionary instead of fetching it again from web.

Comment: If you have their profile information, you should have their ID. Just cache the all data by ID then, and you don't have to distinguish whos logged in. If the cache is too big, just empty some of it.

Comment: When facebooks user logs in I get FBSession object and then I have to make web api call to get their ID and other profile info ( @"SELECT uid, name, pic_big,username FROM user where uid = me()";) ... At this point I get user's ID... And what I want is to avoid this Web API Call ... And to avoid this Web API Call I have to get some info of currently logged in info from FBSession object so I could show user's profile info from my Cache and I wont have to make another Web API call.